# Memory issue/ Cursor shows null pointer

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, nullpointerexception

I am getting the name and email id of the contacts and it works fine in HTC Desire, but whenever i tried to run the code in galaxy tab it shows me No memory in memObj and null pointer on... while (emailCur.moveToNext()) .

Here's my code

```
private void getPeopleList() {
    String name, email;
    Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    c = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            name = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            String id = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
            cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);


             emailCur = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);

            int j = 0;

            while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {

                bindData = new BindData[emailCur.getCount()];
                bindData = new BindData();
                email = emailCur
                        .getString(emailCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                bindData.setEmailId(email);
                bindData.setName(name);
                Log.d("doubt : ", name+"//"+email);
                mArrayList.add(bindData);
                j++;


            }
            emailCur.close();                   
        }
        c.close();

    }


}
```

I am calling this method using worker thread runnable.

If any information is required let me know.

here's my log cat

```
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/IMemory(6180): binder=0xdf3f68 transaction failed    fd=-2147483647, size=0, err=-2147483646 (Unknown error: 2147483646)
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/IMemory(6180): cannot dup fd=-2147483647, size=0, err=-2147483646 (Bad file number)
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/IMemory(6180): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0xdf3f68), size=0, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/JavaBinder(6180): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/JavaBinder(6180): java.lang.RuntimeException: No memory in memObj
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/JavaBinder(6180):     at android.database.CursorWindow.native_init(Native Method)
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/JavaBinder(6180):     at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:518)
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/JavaBinder(6180):     at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:27)
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/JavaBinder(6180):     at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:493)
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/JavaBinder(6180):     at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:496)
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/JavaBinder(6180):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:103)
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/JavaBinder(6180):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
06-29 16:13:26.854: ERROR/JavaBinder(6180):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-29 16:13:26.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 16:13:26.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6388): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 16:13:26.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at com.meomyo.fanaticfaninit.utils.MyCustomList.getPeopleList(MyCustomList.java:172)
06-29 16:13:26.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at com.meomyo.fanaticfaninit.utils.MyCustomList.access$0(MyCustomList.java:144)
06-29 16:13:26.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at com.meomyo.fanaticfaninit.utils.MyCustomList$1.run(MyCustomList.java:121)
06-29 16:13:26.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-29 16:13:26.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-29 16:13:26.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-29 16:13:26.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-29 16:13:26.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 16:13:26.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-29 16:13:26.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6388):     at
```

Comment: which line is it crashing on?

Comment: @Nic: while(emailCur.moveToNext()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the Answer: The Problem is with my ArrayList(mArraylist) that currently i am using, I am passing this arraylist with my adapter also, that is the reason of holding the objects too long for an arraylist. So here's the solution create one Dummy ArrayList Put your data in it and at the time of passing the ArrayList into an adapter copy it into the original ArrayList.

Here's the code.

```
ArrayList<BindData> dummyArrayList= new ArrayList<BindData>
```

inside while loop

```
dummyArrayList.add(bindData);
```

and before creating an instance of Adapter copy this Dummy ArrayList into the original ArrayList(The list that you want to pass into the Adapter)

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getPeopleList();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                  
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mArrayList.clear();
                    for(int i = 0; i < dummyArrayList.size(); i++){
                        mArrayList.add(dummyArrayList.get(i));
                    }
                    dummyArrayList.clear();
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

after that you can create the adapter instance by passing the original Arraylist in it.

```
  MyAdapter myAdapter= new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.contactlistrow, mArrayList);
```

it will work fine.

Thanks

Comment: Find one more Answer: Delete this code " cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
" and it works fine again :).

Answer (score 1):

please can you try

```
if (emailCur.moveToFirst()) {
do {

} while (emailCur.moveToNext());
}
```

instead of `emailCur.moveToNext()`

Comment: Not working..anything else.... i don't think so that wont b an issue... thanks for ans.

Comment: can you please past your logcat?

Comment: @Nick: Inside emailCur i can see the Log Log.d("doubt : ", name+"//"+email);
i am able to get the name nd email id's but at the end i got this Error.

Comment: @PiyushMishra  can you please tell me what is bindData ? in your code because i put your code but getting compile error bindData..

Comment: @Nick: Yah BindData is just a simple class having getter setter method. This code simple wont work coz it just a part of my class, I am using custom adapter also to show the data that i am getting. But i dont think so adapter is creating any problem anywhere.IF you need any code please let me know.